# How to obtain the full url of an Angular view in Global.asax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

In an ASP.NET MVC application, there is `Request.Url` to access the url in `Global.asax`.

But for an Angular application where an url is like `http://domain/#/home`. The `Request.Url` we obtained from `Application_BeginRequest` or `Application_EndRequest` are `http://domain/`. The Angular routes are not included.

It is reasonable because those routes are added at the client side. But is it possible to get the value of the true url in the MVC server side?

---

Update:

Just picked Matteo's answer as the correct one. Let me clarify a bit.

I have been trying this for one purpose: rewrite my url.

In the past, I used to check `Request.ApplicationPath` and manipulate url with string functions or built-in tools like `VirtualPathUtility`.

The need for the hash part is valid because the query string parameters are appended there. For example, I have a url like this:

```
http://[domain]/#/pay/cancel?paymentId=[some guid]
```

The conventional wisdom brought me to `Global.asax` to access those query parameters. I find none. Everything behind the hash tag is conveniently ignored.

So the correct way is to handle that part of url in the client side code. I am using `ui-router`. So for url rewrite/redirect, use `stateProvider.when(oldUrl, newUrl);`. To access query parameters, use `$state.params`.

Lesson learned: think clearly and approach different problem with different mindset.

Comment: That's it. With the ui-router component you have to do exactly as you say. I'm happy to see you found by yourself the right way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way, as the "hash" part of an url is not really part of the url. Have you ever used anchors in a page to create an index? The concept is the same.

Anyway I can't possibly imagine how the hash part could be useful server side. My guess is that you *think* it's useful because you're approaching a problem the wrong way.

If you complement your question with more details, like what you're trying to achieve, it's very possible we can provide you with an appropriate solution.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of agree that I have been approaching the problem the wrong way, like you said.